# TypeError: setTodos is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this error while I am trying to delete the added todo list with

```
const  deleteHandler = () => {
        setTodos(todos.filter((el) => el.id !== todo.id));
        // console.log(todo.id);
    };
```

and I added this handler to the delete button. And When I click on the delete button it shows me TypeError: setTodos is not a function in react.  But I can't understand whats the mistake I have done. Please help me.

```
import React from 'react';

const Todo = ({text, todo, todos, setTodos}) => {
        const  deleteHandler = () => {
            setTodos(todos.filter((el) => el.id !== todo.id));
            // console.log(todo.id);
        };
    return (
        <div className="todo">
            <li className="todo-item">{text}</li>
            <button className="complete-btn">
            <i className="fas fa-check"></i>
            </button>
            <button onClick={deleteHandler} className="trash-btn" >
            <i className="fas fa-trash"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Todo;
```

Comment: `setTodos` looks to be a passed callback function. Are you passing a function to that prop in the parent component of `Todo`? Please add to your question the component code that is rendering `Todo`.

Comment: Yes, I am passing a function the prop in the parent comonent.

Comment: Can you also add the code where you are passing the callback to `Todo `?

Comment: it shows me in the browser:const Todo = ({text, todo, todos, setTodos}) => {
  4 |         const  deleteHandler = () => {
> 5 |             setTodos(todos.filter((el) => el.id !== todo.id));
  6 |             // console.log(todo.id);
  7 |         };
  8 |     return (

Comment: John, be that as it may, we can't verify that if you don't include the calling component code. Clearly by the time `deleteHandler` is invoked `setTodos` is *not* a function. Perhaps there is simply a typo and you only *think* you are passing a function.

Answer (score 1):

[code screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj2w0.jpg)

Maybe you forgot about this props:

On app.js:
`<TodoList todos={todos} setTodos={setTodos} />`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing setTodos is not a callback function. Here is example code. It may help you:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

export const Todos = ( ) => {
    const todoDatas = [
        {id: 1, value: 'Do 1'},
        {id: 2, value: 'Do 2'},
        {id: 3, value: 'Do 3'},
    ]

    const [todos, setTodos] = useState(todoDatas);

   return <div>
       {todos.map(todo => <Todo
           text={todo.value}
           todo={todo}
           setTodos={setTodos}
           todos={todos}
       />)}
    </div>;
}

const Todo = ({text, todo, todos, setTodos}) => {
    const  deleteHandler = () => {
        setTodos(todos.filter((el) => el.id !== todo.id));
        // console.log(todo.id);
    };
    return (
        <div className="todo">
            <li className="todo-item">{text}</li>
            <button className="complete-btn">
                <i className="fas fa-check"></i>
            </button>
            <button onClick={deleteHandler} className="trash-btn" >
                <i className="fas fa-trash"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Todo;
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because your data is not an array. The .map() function only works with arrays.

```
    {todos.map((todo) => (
        <Todo
            setTodo={setTodos}
```

instead of:

```
        {todos.map((todo) => (
        <Todo
            setTodos={setTodos}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here is steps that may help you:

1. pass setTodos prop in your TodoList component App.js

`<TodoList setTodos={setTodos} todos={todos}/>`

2. Remember to include your todo prop in the Todo component in your TodoList.js

`<Todo todos={todos} setTodos={setTodos} key={todo.id} todo={todo} text={todo.text} />`

This helped me.